# Are instance methods capable of being concurrently executed by default in java?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

I know about the synchronized keyword, but I want to make sure that I have a clear understanding.

So, if I don't use the synchronized keyword, an instance variable may be overwritten by two threads, but if I do use the synchronized keyword only 1 thread may enter the method at a time. Right?

Comment: @VictorSorokin I think the question in the title actually is: *Can instance methods be executed concurrently by default in java?* - in which case the answer is yes.

Comment: Someone should edit the question

Comment: Is the new title better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two threads enter an un-synchronized method and update some shared state, then it can lead to inconsistencies.

```
public synchronized void method(){ 
      //only one thread will be able to enter (IF SAME INSTANCE)
}
```

But it also establishes a **happens-before** relationship. This is visibility part of multithreading.

> Two actions can be ordered by a happens-before relationship. If one
>   action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and
>   ordered before the second.

[Happens-before](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) JLS.

Answer (score 2):

> if I don't use the synchronized keyword, an instance variable may be overwritten by two threads

it won't be "overwritten" but it can be executed by two threads simultaneously, leading to possible inconsistencies if it is not designed to handle such a situation.

> if I do use the synchronized keyword only 1 thread may enter the method at a time.

That is correct if you make the method `synchronized`: that keyword provides a certain number of guarantees, including mutual exclusion.